# Adding lead zeros with precision in python

Tags: python

**How can I get a float number with leading zeros and decimal precision?**

For example:

```
number = 1.8315454
```

and I want to print **"01.83"**

Answer (score 4):

```
print(f"{number:05.2f}")
```

The 0 indicates to fill with leading 0, the 5 is the total of characters in the output: digits + decimal point, the "." indicates that decimal places should be printed, the "2" indicates that 2 decimal digits are wanted, the 'f' indicates it is a floating point number.

Answer (score 0):

use string formating (f-string):

```
number = 1.8315454
print(f"{number:05.2f}")
```

output:

```
>> 01.83
```